# Bootstrap carousel previous control not sliding correctly

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

http://bootply.com/94444

The above bootstrap carousel is a 3 column layout and advances by 1 item at a time but when I click the previous scroll they slide in a weird way, how can I stop them sliding this way and make them slide similar to the next control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%; }` to your `CSS` as well.

```
.carousel-inner .active.left { left: -33%; }
.carousel-inner .active.right { left: 33%; }
.carousel-inner .next        { left:  33%; }
.carousel-inner .prev        { left: -33%; }
.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {background-image:none;}
```

http://bootply.com/98501